# Using Event handler or something similar

Tags: button, adobe, flash-cs5

I'm working on Adobe Flash CS5 and on actionscript 3 - My question is how can I make a button that only becomes available to click on once the four other buttons have been clicked and the scenes have been accessed?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your 5 buttons are always available on the timeline *and* they are at the top document level (if not, we need to make some adjustments). Let's also assume that, from your question, you're not ready for the best practice of a document Class file, so this will be written as timeline script.

```
//assumes the 4 buttons are on the stage, named button1, button2, etc.
var prerequisiteButtons:Array = [button1, button2, button3, button4];
var prerequisitesClicked:Array /*of Boolean*/ = [];

coyButton.enabled = false;//your fifth button, who plays hard to get

//loop through and listen for clicks on your prerequisite buttons
for each (var button:DisplayObject in buttons) {
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkAllClicked);
}

//check to see if all the buttons have been clicked
function checkAllClicked(e:Event):void {
    //find the button in the prerequisite buttons array
    var buttonIndex:int = prerequisiteButtons.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
    //set the matching index to true in the array that keeps track of what has been clicked
    prerequisitesClicked[buttonIndex] = true;
    //count how many of them have been clicked
    var prerequisiteDoneCount:int = 0;
    for (var i:int = 0; i< prerequisitesClicked.length; i++) {
        if (prerequisitesClicked[i]) prerequisiteDoneCount++;
    }
    //if all the buttons have been clicked, enable the button (may also want to add a listener here)
    if (prerequisiteDoneCount==prerequisiteButtons.length) coyButton.enabled = true;
}
```